# Why would creating a simple, custom installer application in .NET be a bad idea?

Tags: windows, installation

I am sure that the systems, on which the installer will run, have .NET framework > 3.5 installed.
I feel comfortable with .NET and I have done similar "installer" in the past, although for just some 50 people.
If I were to use some existing installer then I would have to do some research (which one to choose and how to use it). Then why should I bother?

Comment: what about using an .msi installer?  writing your own .NET installer app seems like re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, an installer is needed only when there is a need of copying a number of files copied to various paths, creation of registry sets, configuring ini/xml/config files. If these hurdles are not there, there is no need of an installer.

Else, An installer is strongly recommended to reduce humane errors during the manual setup process.

Comment: even if your application itself only needs a directory of files and nothing more an installer can still be preferable.  for example, to support uninstall through the add/remove programs you need to add registry entries.  and you'll usually want a shortcut on the desktop and/or start menu.  I could imagine users preferring that this be done for them even when the app is just a directory of files.  Not to mention if you want to get your app logo certified then I believe you have to package it up as an .msi anyway.